# how to import text from a notepad as a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
f=open('New.txt') 
lines=f.readlines() 
tmp = (lines[0]) 
if tmp == ("word7"): 
    print ("ok") 
else: 
    print ("not ok")
```

Unfortunately the variable imported into `tmp` can not be compared with string `"word7"` and I don't understand why.

Comment: `if tmp.strip() == ("word7"):`

Comment: Seeing questions like this more and more often I just have to ask: Could someone explain to me what "a notepad" is?

Comment: do you mean the comparison returns False or that the comparison returns an Error? You say "can not be compared"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readlines()` includes a newline (`\n`) char at the end of each line.

You're not taking that into account.

Try this:

```
tmp = lines[0].rstrip()
```

Technically, you could or should do this, if you only want to remove newlines:

```
tmp = lines[0][:-1]
```

This works because you are guaranteed to have a newline on each line. This will preserve leading and trailing spaces, in case those are important.

If you don't care at all about other leading or trailing spaces or tabs, then you can do this:

```
tmp = lines[0].strip()
```

This may be acceptable if you're not concerned about formatting within the lines.

Relevant [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) to review, including `readlines`.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, and I was aware that the OPs code should be returning False. I have edited my post to include this, however, I would urge the OP to accept your answer, I'm going to delete mine if possible, although you can't delete accepted answers it seems...

Comment: Thanks, @Totem.  Very kind of you.  Happy Holidays.